# What is a “token” creature or structure?

Tags: scrolls

What is a “token” creature or structure? I know I've seen the phrases “Token Structure” and “Token Creature” on a scroll during play, but I can't find it on any of my scrolls in the library and I don't know what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A token unit is one which was summoned by some effect during combat, rather than from a scroll in the player's hand.

The consequence is that such units cannot be returned to the player's hand as scrolls (which can otherwise be done by such scrolls as *Callback*, *Pushback*, or *Divine Mark*).

[(Source)](http://www.scrollsguide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=18426#p18426)

Comment: Same as Magic the Gathering then. Also, why have you not accepted your answer?

Comment: @WorldEngineer I've never played M:tG so I wouldn't know. I searched the web and didn't find an _obvious_ answer, so I decided to make there be one. I didn't accept the answer because someone else might well have a better answer: maybe I have some facts wrong; maybe there's some useful historical context like in your comment.

Comment: Basically in Magic and other such games, when you've got a generated critter or whatever you'd use a token (traditionally a coin, dice or mancala piece) to represent said critter or whatever. Wizards and possibly other companies now sell "Token" cards for specific token critters (like Goblins or Saporlings [little fungal spawn thingies] for Magic and maybe something a drone in another game).